# A simple reverse engineering of calculation.

Tags: advice

I have a formula $x=\frac{1}{\frac{Y}{1000}}$ which is the calculation for converting Parallax to Parsec.  I need to reverse it but can't remember how to reverse $1/$ .

So for a Parallax of $49.56$, divide by $1000$ then divide $1$ by $0.04956$ equals $20.17756$.

If I have $20.17756$, how do i get back to $49.56$ via $0.04956$.

I am looking for a simple explanation, one that can be calculated in a non-scientific calculator.

Thanks.

Comment: $Y/1000 = 1/x$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $\frac{y}{1000}$:
$$\frac{y}{1000}x=\frac{y}{1000}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{y}{1000}}=\frac{\frac{y}{1000}}{\frac{y}{1000}}=1 $$
Now divide by $x$ (note that then $x\neq 0$):
$$\frac{y}{1000}=\frac{y}{1000}\cdot\frac{x}{x}=\frac{\frac{y}{1000}x}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$$
Multiply by $1000$:
$$y=1000\cdot \frac{y}{1000}=1000\cdot \frac{1}{x}=\frac{1000}{x}$$

Comment: So the answer is to divide 1 by 20.17756 then multiple 1000

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser Yes, but this is equivalent to directly dividing 1000 by 20.17756, which is easier to do.